# SQL Case statement In Where clause: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Not sure where I'm going wrong in my `CASE` statement. I'm trying to create a filter in my `WHERE` clause to only show products based on the selected platform the user selects. I have played around with this for awhile and Googled a lot of examples bit nothing seemed to be close. I'm sure its something simple I'm missing. Need fresh pair of eyes to point it out. I'll keep digging in mean time.

```
    @Platform AS INT,
    @Type AS INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        [Product_Name],
        [Product_Description],
        [Product_Release],
        [Product_Image],
        [Windows_PC],
        [Linux],
        [Mac],
        [Android],
        [Fire_TV],
        [Amazon_App_Store],
        [Google_Play_Store],
        [X_Box],
        [Switch],
        [Playstation],
        [Link_Game_Play],
        [Link_Twitter],
        [Link_Download],
        [Link_Web],
        [Available_Now],
        [New_Release],
        [Coming_Soon],
        [Open_Beta]
    FROM
        [White_Box_Gaming].[dbo].[WBG_Product_Profile]
    WHERE
        CASE 
            WHEN @Platform = 1 THEN [Windows_PC] = 1
            WHEN @Platform = 2 THEN [Mac] = 1
            WHEN @Platform = 3 THEN [Linux] = 1
            WHEN @Platform = 4 THEN [Android] = 1
            ELSE [Windows_PC] = 1
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Select_Portal_Games, Line 37
> Incorrect syntax near '='.

I know I have a syntax issue. I'm just not formatting something right in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Your `case` is not a statement, it's an _expression_. However, it's better to use regular AND/OR in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use simple logic:

```
WHERE (@Platform = 1 AND [Windows_PC] = 1) OR
      (@Platform = 2 AND [Mac] = 1) OR
      (@Platform = 3 AND [Linux] = 1) OR
      (@Platform = 4 AND [Android] = 1) OR
      (@Platform NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4) AND [Windows_PC] = 1)
```

The condition for "1" is redundant with the `else`.  I'm not sure if that is a typo.  If not, you can remove the first condition.

Comment: Oh that's a slick way to do it. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

`CASE` is an **expression** that produces a result. It is *not* just an `if` block for selecting which code to run. So instead, you need to do something like this:

```
WHERE 1 = 
    CASE WHEN @Platform = 2 THEN [Mac] 
        WHEN @Platform = 3 THEN [Linux] 
        WHEN @Platform = 4 THEN [Android]
    ELSE 
        [Windows_PC]
    END
```

Comment: I'm a little confused on the WHERE 1 = Part then it goes into the CASE statement. Is that a typo?

Comment: No, that is intentional. `CASE` is _not a statement_! It's an expression, that produces a value. The code in my answer uses the value from the `CASE` expression for the right-hand side of the equality comparison.

Comment: Oh I see what your saying now. I've never seen it done that way before. Looks a little weird but I guess it gets the job done. Kudos